# How to express "feel hatred"

Tags: перевод, грамматика, падежи

Is it simply **чувствовать ненависть**?

In a sentence like **Он не чувствовал ненависти к своим врагам**, what is the case of ненависти? I can rule out *nominative plural* and *prepositional singular*, but that leaves *genitive singular*, *dative singular*, and *accusative plural*. I want to make sure I'm thinking of ненависть in the Russian way here (not just a translation of "hatred").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Испытывать ненависть** is probably the best choice in terms of style, but **чувствовать** is the go-to, catch-all term you're generally more likely to hear. **Ощущать** is another option but with **ненависть**, it somehow strikes me as unpleasantly wannabe-bookish. I could be wrong.

The case on **ненависти** is genitive singular; the reason for it is just the negative on the verb.

**Ненависть** is very much a translation of "hatred" — unless, conversely, I'm missing something uniquely English about the word; but I don't think I am. Both are the most generic term available in its respective language.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the somewhat more flowery **питать ненависть**. Literally to "feed" or "nourish", here meaning "harbor".